# Run snakemake rules iteratively

Tags: python, config, sample, snakemake

So I thought I was finally grasping snakemake, but when trying to run several different data files, I realized it doesn't work as I though. This is the Snakefile:

```
import pandas as pd

configfile: "config.json"
experiments = pd.read_csv(config["experiments"], sep = '\t')
experiments['Name'] = [filename.split('/')[-1].split('.fa')[0] for filename in experiments['Files']]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}{fr}.fq", output = config["output"],
            fr = (['_forward_paired', '_reverse_paired'] if experiments["Files"].str.contains(',').tolist() else ''),
               name = experiments['Name'])

rule preprocess:
    input:
        experiments["Files"].str.split(',')
    output:
        expand("{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}{fr}.fq", output = config["output"],
            fr = (['_forward_paired', '_reverse_paired'] if experiments["Files"].str.contains(',').tolist() else ''),
               name = experiments['Name'])
    threads:
        config["threads"]
    run:
        shell("python preprocess.py -i {reads} -t {threads} -o {output} -adaptdir MOSCA/Databases/illumina_adapters -rrnadbs MOSCA/Databases/rRNA_databases -d {data_type}",
            output = config["output"], data_type = experiments["Data type"].tolist(), reads = ",".join(input))
```

this is the config file:

```
{
  "output": "test_snakemake",
  "threads": 14,
  "experiments": "experiments.tsv"
}
```

and this is the experiments file

```
Files   Sample  Data type   Condition
path/to/mg_R1.fastq,path/to/mg_R2.fastq Sample  dna
path/to/a/0.01/mt_0.01a_R1.fastq,path/to/a/0.01/mt_0.01a_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c1
path/to/b/0.01/mt_0.01b_R1.fastq,path/to/b/0.01/mt_0.01b_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c1
path/to/c/0.01/mt_0.01c_R1.fastq,path/to/c/0.01/mt_0.01c_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c1
path/to/a/1/mt_1a_R1.fastq,path/to/a/1/mt_1a_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c2
path/to/b/1/mt_1b_R1.fastq,path/to/b/1/mt_1b_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c2
path/to/c/1/mt_1c_R1.fastq,path/to/c/1/mt_1c_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c2
path/to/a/100/mt_100a_R1.fastq,path/to/a/100/mt_100a_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c3
path/to/b/100/mt_100b_R1.fastq,path/to/b/100/mt_100b_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c3
path/to/c/100/mt_100c_R1.fastq,path/to/c/100/mt_100c_R2.fastq   Sample  rna c3
```

What I want to do is have preprocess rule treat each row separately. I thought that was the way shell interpreted the command, and it would run the command `python preprocess.py -i path/to/mg_R1.fastq,path/to/mg_R2.fastq -t 14 -o test_snakemake -adaptdir MOSCA/Databases/illumina_adapters -rrnadbs MOSCA/Databases/rRNA_databases -d dna`, instead it tries to join ALL rows and run this to all samples simultaneously `python preprocess.py -i path/to/mg_R1.fastq,path/to/mg_R2.fastq,path/to/a/0.01/mt_0.01a_R1.fastq,path/to/a/0.01/mt_0.01a_R2.fastq,path/to/b/0.01/mt_0.01b_R1.fastq,path/to/b/0.01/mt_0.01b_R2.fastq,... -t 14 -o test_snakemake -adaptdir MOSCA/Databases/illumina_adapters -rrnadbs MOSCA/Databases/rRNA_databases -d dna rna rna rna rna rna rna rna rna rna`.

How can I make snakemake consider each row separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common mistake.  The thing to remember is that rules should work for a single sample.  Snakemake will take your paths (with wildcards) and generate specific jobs from the rules.  You've written something that takes all inputs and all outputs, then I presume, preprocess.py expects one input/output.

Instead, consider one file at a time.  For the output, `"{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}{fr}.fq"`, how do you generate that file?  You would have to match to an input file in your experiments dataframe using the name as a key.

```
def preprocess_input(wildcards):
    # get files with matching names
    df = experiments.loc[experiments['Name'] == wildcards.name, 'Files']
    # get first value (in case multiple) and split on commas
    return df.iloc[0].split(',')

rule preprocess:
    input:
        preprocess_input
    output:
        "{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}{fr}.fq"
    threads:
        config["threads"]
    shell:
        'python preprocess.py -i {reads} -t {threads} -o {config[output]} ...'
```

That uses an input function to find the correct input files from the output file.  It's not perfect but should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using a version of your solution has put it working! I might just start understanding wildcards now...